# Where should a level 110 character level and or quest?

Tags: trickster

I started playing Trickster Online again, my character's a level 110 Cat. Where should I grind monsters/quest?

The last places I remember playing (two years ago) were Ghost Blue, which was getting too easy and I ran out of quests, and Rose Gardens, which was hard but I had lots of unfinished quests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is this guy's guide: [Carlos' Grinding Guide](http://forum.ntreev.net/trickster/forums/t/47975.aspx)

It says: "Level 110~130 ---> Nora Sewer (BEST PLACE), Phantom School Art Room (for mages), Phantom School Music Room, Path to Snow Hill. Hunting any monster around."

Unfortunately this guy's is for people who have finished quests. I don't really know where you could grind quests, this is just for monsters. Hope this at least helps some though :)

Comment: I've done most, so that should do. I'll just have to get into Nora's sewer. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)